# Consequences and state-of-the-art of NP ≠ ZPP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np

Consider the complexity classes [$\mathsf{NP}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo%3aN#np) and [$\mathsf{ZPP}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo%3aZ#zpp). Whether the two classes are equal is an open question, but as far as I know, $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{ZPP}$ is not known to imply $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$. For example, there are many inapproximability results depending on $\mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{ZPP}$, but what evidence do we have for believing they would indeed be not equal?

In other words, what would be the consequences of $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{ZPP}$? Is it safe to claim that likewise for $\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$, many theorists also believe $\mathsf{NP}$ is not equal to $\mathsf{ZPP}$?

Comment: Many experts conjecture that $\mathsf{BPP} = \mathsf{P}$. That is one of the main reasons why many experts conjecture that $\mathsf{BPP}$ is not equal to $\mathsf{NP}$ (as most experts conjecture that $\mathsf{NP}$ is not equal to $\mathsf{P}$). $\mathsf{ZPP}$ is between $\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{BPP}$ and therefore it is a common conjecture that it is not equal to $\mathsf{NP}$.

Comment: aside from complexity theory considerations, the usual arguments why we do not believe P = NP work for BPP = NP: a lot of people have tried to come up with fast algorithms for NP-complete problems, and it's not like they haven't thought about Monte Carlo or Las Vegas algorithms, too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to claim that most theorists believe that $\mathsf{NP}$ is not equal to $\mathsf{ZPP}$ -- and that most theorists believe that $\mathsf{NP}$ is not equal to $\mathsf{BPP}$.

One consequence of $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{ZPP}$ is that computational cryptography is impossible.  This is described as the world Algorithmica in Impagliazzo's famous five worlds:

- [A Personal View of Average-Case Complexity](http://www.cs.ucsd.edu/users/russell/average.ps).  Russell Impagliazzo.  1995 Complexity Conference. (A PDF version is [here](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/ri5svetu.pdf)).

Note that as far as practical consequences go, Impagliazzo says it doesn't matter much whether we have $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$ or $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{BPP}$ (he even calls the latter the "moral equivalent" of $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$).

See also [What if P = NP?](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2004/05/what-if-p-np.html) for additional practical consequences (assuming the constants hidden by asymptotic notation are not too large).

I don't know whether there are any surprising implications for complexity classes.

Comment: For complexity classes, if NP = BPP, then PH collapses to the second level. I consider NP = BPP itself more shocking, though. Also P $\neq$ NP = BPP implies $\mathsf{DTIME}(2^{O(n)}) \subseteq \mathsf{size}(2^{o(n)})$